# Split one column into two column oracle

Tags: oracle, string-parsing

This is how my table look like:

```
Number1     Type    REASON_CODE ACCEPT_TYPE CREATION_DATE
30745578    MAIN    0                  A    11/8/2014 1:57
30745578    MAIN    0                  B    11/8/2014 2:02
007159812X  MAIN    0                  A    11/3/2014 11:16
```

This is how I want the results:

```
Number1     Type    REASON_CODE ACCEPT1 ACCEPT2 CREATION_DATE1  CREATION_DATE2
30745578    MAIN    0                 A    B    11/8/2014 1:57  11/8/2014 2:02
007159812X  MAIN    0                 A    A    11/3/2014 11:16 11/3/2014 11:16
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If you need them as real database columns you should Look up the [PIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) command.

Otherwise you can use LISTAGG() to build a long Text with all relevant info.